# How to use 2LC and not repeat SQL query in Hibernate when row doesn't exists in database

Tags: hibernate, infinispan, second-level-cache

Can Hibernate second level cache (2LC) do caching for not found records in database?

I query Account entity by primary key accountNumber - it is configured as @Cachable.
If I execute em.find('AA') first time then hibernate will check 2LC, it is missed in 2LC then SQL query will be executed. There is no account AA in DB so em.find call return null.

If I execute em.find('AA') second time in another transaction then hibernate will execute SQL query again even SQL was executed before.

Is it possible that Hibernate will save null from first executed query so another SQL is not required until AA key will be invalidated in cache?

I use EAP 6.2.4, Hibernate 4.2.7, Infinispan 5.2.7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Even with Hibernate ORM 5.x, the 2LC API does not include this, and it's not possible for the 2LC implementation to return any hint that the entity cannot be in the DB either (even though the implementation could hold some kind of tombstone and know that).

Since this might be quite useful at times, please log JIRA with feature request.

Comment: Thanks. I know also about query cache which I'm going to use in my case. I preferred using 2LC with primary key to keep my application less depended on SQL and more closer to querying by primary key to test performance against 1LC after changing DAOs.

Comment: Yes, but query cache has some performance impact, and there's also a short window when it can provide stale result.

Comment: Can you explain more performance impact of using query cache? In my case I use entities updated once a day so query cache won't be invalidated often. Stale results ? It would be nice if you have some link explaining it.

Comment: OK, the performance impact is only on the writes, as 2LC needs to update the last write timestamp of given entity type. And the staleness happens only in clustered mode, as timestamp updates are propagated asynchronously by default. See http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.1/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#caching-provider-infinispan-config-query-timestamps (the info box and the paragraph below)

Comment: I have linked 5.1 docs, but the part about query cache holds for 4.2 as well (+ there are few bugs in 4.2).